# starting a new activity in a list that is in a tab

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

I have 4 tabs and in 1 of the tabs (tab 3) I have a list with 2 options.  Is there a way to start a new activity when I click one of the options?  I tried changing Activity to ListActivity but my app crashes as soon as it loads.  Would I need to implement something else to this for it to work?

code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

TabHost th;
ListView libraryView;
String libraryList[] = {"Item1", "Item2"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Always do this at the start.
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_white_text, R.id.library_list_content, libraryList);
    libraryView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    libraryView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Creating the TabHost and gathering its ID for usage.
    th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);        
    th.setup();

    TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    specs.setIndicator("tab1");
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    specs.setIndicator("tab2");
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    specs.setIndicator("tab3");
    th.addTab(specs);

    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag4");
    specs.setContent(R.id.tab4);
    specs.setIndicator("tab4");
    th.addTab(specs);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.listView1:


    }
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/black" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </ListView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp" >
        </TabWidget>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add on click listeners for listview

Comment: Hey RajaReddy P I implemented OnClickListener and could you give a small example on how I would do this please or have a reference to how to go about doing this. Updating the code.

Comment: I added the onClick(View v), was this the right step forward and if it was, was the switch, case R.id.listView1 going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Add on click listeners for listview like this

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {                
    // depending on item positions create intents for activity. 
       }
});
```

Comment: omg thank you soooo much Raja <3<3<3 you are the freakin man/woman. thank you once again